# Is it true that $c_0(X)^* = \ell_1(X^*)$ ?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove this that but I can't . Any help/reference ?

Comment: Do you mean just $l_1(x)$ not $l_1(X^*)$?

Comment: I think this is true, as a special case of results concerning the dual of an injective tensor product being sometimes equal to the projective tensor product of the duals. However, this is something I "know of" rather than "know", if you see what I mean, so I'll just stop here and wait for true experts to weigh in.

Comment: Also, how did the question arise? (I am not sure whether a hint or explanation would be more useful than a mere reference.)

Comment: This is an easy exercise.  I cannot imagine what your difficulty might  be.  If you describe what you tried and where you got stuck perhaps someone can help.

Comment: 
I'm studying an article an the author seems to use this argument. See, he writes
\begin{equation}
c_0 (\ell_2)^*** \approx \ell_\infy(\ell_2)^*.
\end{equation}

I've already proven that $\ell_p(X)^* \approx \ell_q(X^*)$, where $1 < p < \infty$ and $q$ is the conjugate of $p$. I also proved that $\ell_1(X)^* \approx \ell_\infty(X^*)$.

I think I can prove that $c_0(X)^*=\ell_1(X^*)$ if I suppose that $X$ is reflexive -- and that's the case in the article. But I'm hoping this result is valid for a general $X$ normed space. 


Comment: Yes, it is true, and the proof is essentially the same as what you said you did prove. I cannot imagine how you can prove this for reflexive $X$ but not for general $X$. 

Comment: Hi Bill, here is what I tried. 

Given a functional $f$ in $c_0(X)^*$, I'll try to define an element of  $\ell_1(X^*)$ that depends on $f$.

Define $\pi_n\colon: X \to c_0 (X)$ by $\pi_n(x) = (0,\ldots,0,x,0,\ldots)$. The natural idea would be
\begin{equation} 
f \mapsto (f \circ \pi_1, f \circ \pi_2, \ldots),
\end{equation}
but first I need to prove that $(f \circ \pi_1, f \circ \pi_2, \ldots) \in \ell_1(X^*)$, that is, I must show that
\begin{equation}
\sum^\infty_{n=1} \lVert f \circ \pi_n \rVert < \infty.
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, sure; but whether or not $X$ is reflexive is irrelevant, and the same problem occurs in proving the things you said you did prove. Are you hung up by the fact that $F\circ \pi_n$ need not achieve its norm?  Then just choose a unit vector $x_n$ s.t. $F\circ \pi_n (x_n) \ge (1-\epsilon) \|F\circ \pi_n\|$.

Comment: Then, of course, you look at, for each n, the vector $(x_1,\dots,x_n,0,0,0,\dots)$.

Comment: From Hahn-Banach we know that, given $x \neq 0$, there's a functional $f$ such that $\lVert f \rVert = 1$ and $f(x) = \lVert x \rVert$. It follows that, if $X$ is reflexive, given $f \neq 0$, there's an $x \in X$ such that $\lVert x \rVert = 1$ and $f(x) = \lVert f \rVert$.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For each $1 \le j \le n$, choose $x_j$ such that $\lVert x_j \rVert = 1$ and $f \circ \pi_j(x_j) = \lVert f \circ \pi_j \rVert$. Then
\begin{equation}
\sum^n_{j=1} \lVert f \circ \pi_j \rVert = \lvert f (x_1,\ldots,x_n,0,0,\ldots) \rvert \le \lVert f \rVert.
\end{equation}

Comment: see, I don't have $f \circ \pi_n(x_n) \ge (1- \varepsilon) \lVert f \circ \pi_n \rVert$, but I have $\lvert f \circ \pi_n(x_n) \rvert \ge (1- \varepsilon) \lVert f \circ \pi_n \rVert$

Comment: I don't understand your problem, Rafael. You just multiply $x_n$ by a complex number of modulus one to make $f\circ \pi_n(x_n)$ non negative.

Comment: but I'm not supposing that the field is $\mathbb{R}$.  So, instead of getting
\begin{equation}
\sum^n_{j=1} \lVert f \circ \pi_j \rVert \le \frac{\sum^n_{j=1} f \circ \pi_j (x_j) }{1-\varepsilon} = \frac { f (x_1,\ldots,x_n,0,0,\ldots)} {1-\varepsilon}\le \frac {\lVert f \rVert}{1-\varepsilon}
\end{equation}
I'm gettin
\begin{equation}
\sum^n_{j=1} \lVert f \circ \pi_j \rVert \le \frac{\sum^n_{j=1} \lvert f \circ \pi_j (x_j) \rvert}{1-\varepsilon} \le \text{?}
\end{equation}

Comment: sorry, i made some typos, and i can't fix the posts, so I delete and rewrite...

Comment: u mean by rotating $f \circ \pi_j (x_j)$ ? 

sorry, I'm embarassed, but I barely work with complex numbers :) 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

True. For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$  consider the inclusion to the $n$-th coordinate   $j _ n : X\to c _ 0(X)$ which is right inverse to the evaluation at $n$, so that $(j _ n x)(n)= x$, for any $x\in X$. Let  $j _ n ^ T : c _ 0(X) ^ * \to X^*$ its transpose operator. Any $\eta \in c _ 0(X)^ * $ defines a sequence $y:\mathbb{N}\to X ^ *$ such that $y(n)   := j _ n ^T \eta $. 
The $\ell _ 1(X^*)$- norm of $y$ is 
$$\|y\|_ { \ell _ 1 (X^*)}=\sum _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\,  \|y(n)\| _ {X ^ *} = \sum _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\, \, \sup _ {\|x\| _ X \le 1} \langle y(n), x  \rangle=$$$$ = \sup _ {m\in\mathbb{N}}\, \, \sup _ {\|\xi\| _ { c _ {0} (X)} \le 1} \, \sum _{n\le m}\, \langle y(n),   \xi(n)  \rangle =$$$$=  \sup _ {\|\xi\| _ { c _ {0} (X)} \le 1} \, \langle \eta,  \xi  \rangle = \|\eta\| _  {c _ 0(X)^*}\, \, .$$
This shows that the inclusion $\ell _ 1(X^*)\to c _ 0(X)^ * $ is actually a linear (surjective) isometry.